# Select specific mapped ITEM - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an onClick event, that will select the pressed mapped item. Could anyone help?

```
   const renderExample= () => {
      return example.map((arrayItem, i) => {
        const example = arrayItem.example;
        const song =
          arrayItem.song ||
          "urltosong";
...
```

then in return

```
 <div key={i}>
                <SELECTABLE>
                  {example}
                </SELECTABLE>
                <SONG>{song}</SONG>
          </div>
```

render     `return <div>{renderData()}</div>;`

At the moment I have a list of selectable'examples' rendering. But I want to know which example has been pressed by the user specifically.

Comment: You can pass a value in the onClick event, e.g. onClick={() => myOnClickMethod(mySongId)}

Answer (score 0):

You can play with it like this:

```
// Supposing you're using React Functional Component

// Click handler
const handleSelect = (elementIndex) => {
  console.log(`You clicked on element with key ${elementIndex}`)
}

// render()
// ... some other to-render stuff
// implying that code below have access to element's index (i in your map)

<Selectable onClick={e => handleSelect(i)}>
  {example}
</Selectable>

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the complete item to the handleClick to play around. The code would be

```
const App = () => {

    function handleClick(item){
        console.log('item,item);
    }

    function renderData(){
        // assuming you have data in example array
        return example && example.map(item=> {
            const example = arrayItem.example;
            const song =arrayItem.song || "urltosong";
            return (
                <div key={i} onClick={()=>{handleClick(item)}>
                <SELECTABLE>
                  {example}
                </SELECTABLE>
                <SONG>{song}</SONG>
            </RecentMessages>
          </div>
            )
        })
    }

    return <div>{renderData()}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain `state` for selected song and update when selection change.
[Here is minimal working sample with stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rjhqte?file=index.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const songs = ["first song", "song 2", "hello song"];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      song: 'hello song'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={(ev) => this.setState({song: ev.target.value})} value={this.state.song}>
          {songs.map(x => <option value={x}> {x} </option>)}
        </select>
        <p>
          {this.state.song}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```